# Where disappeared the method TextView.getTextColor(Context context, TypedArray typedArray, int defStyle) in new Android 5.0?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-5.0-lollipop

After sdk updating to Android 5.0 disappeared the method `TextView.getTextColor(Context context, TypedArray typedArray, int defStyle)`. 
I used this method for my custom TextView (for `int colorId` definition from xml). 
So how to determine`int color id` from xml?

Comment: For anyone curious, this method was removed because android.R.styleable is neither public nor stable. As a result, passing a TypedArray into any framework View is unsafe because the array indices will not match up with the internally used android.R.styleable arrays. This will break your app in ways that are difficult to debug, so we removed all of these methods.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code for getting color for TextView:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourComponentId);
int tv_color = tv.getTextColors().getDefaultColor();
```

or you can also get the color for normal text like this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourComponentId);
int tv_color = tv.getCurrentTextColor();
```

In case of using the first example, you can also get the color for various states using

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourComponentId);
ColorStateList colorStateList = tv.getTextColors();
int tv_color colorStateList.getColorForState(states, failColor);
```

Hope this helps.

Reference: [getColorForState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html#getColorForState(int[],%20int))

Comment: and what is DefaultColor? if developer inputted concrete int color value, how can i taki this?

Comment: @xoxol_89 it returns the concrete int color just like those defined in Color class.

Comment: @xoxol_89 getCurrentTextColor method from TextView class returns the same value.

Answer (score 1):

It has been removed indeed as you can see in the API diff:
https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/21/changes.html

You can still use this variant:

[`public final ColorStateList getTextColors()`](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/21/changes/android.widget.TextView.html)

Comment: can you give me concrete reference to https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/21/changes.html about TextView?

Comment: @xoxol_89 https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/21/changes/android.widget.TextView.html

Comment: but how take color resource id from ColorStateList?